# Show page in WordPress navigation depending on who is logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I understand that I can choose to show/hide a page for logged in users by using the following:

```
<?
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
<li><a href="#">Link Title</a></li>
}
?>
```

But is it possible to show a page only to a certain user? For example I want 'John' to see a page but not 'Bob' so can I do something like:

```
<?
if ( is_John_logged_in() ) {
<li><a href="#">Link Title</a></li>
}
?>
```

Any advice would be brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the function [get_currentuserinfo();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) to retrieve information about the current logged user.

```
global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
  echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
  echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_current_user_id` to get the id of the currently logged in user.

If it's 0, it means nobody is logged in.

It's a numerical value (so if the user changes their username, it will still work)

So, an example:

```
<?
  if ( get_current_user_id() ==123 ) {
    <li><a href="#">Link Title</a></li>
  }
?>
```

A more maintainable approach maybe to do this based on roles (admin, editor etc...)
Just a thought, however

Comment: I tried this but I get: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request. - Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[get_currentuserinfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) could help you... it has all the info of the current logged in user...

like

```
if ($current_user->user_login == 'reigel' ) {
    // do something...
}
```

just check the link for more info..

Comment: I tried this but also get: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request. - Any ideas?

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) is most likely a problem on `.htaccess`. I get that a lot when I was new on godaddy...

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [username_exists](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists), here you can specify User ID or nickname and display your content accordingly.